# Augeas tasks are shown as changed, although the file wasn´t changed

Tags: puppet-dashboard, augeas

I have installed puppet-dashboard and noticed that all my augeas tasks are shown as "changed". I would expect that augeas automatically checks wether the value to be set **is** already set and in such case would do nothing.

My recipe:

```
$puppet_conf = "/etc/puppet/puppet.conf"
file { "${puppet_conf}": }

augeas { "puppet_conf":
        context => "/files/${puppet_conf}/",
        changes => [
                "set agent/report true",
        ],
        require => File["${puppet_conf}"],
}
```

Normal run when the value has already been set before:

```
info: Applying configuration version '1363882751'
debug: Augeas[puppet_conf](provider=augeas): Opening augeas with root /, lens path , flags 0
debug: Augeas[puppet_conf](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection
debug: Augeas[puppet_conf](provider=augeas): Opening augeas with root /, lens path , flags 0
debug: Augeas[puppet_conf](provider=augeas): sending command 'set' with params ["/files//etc/puppet/puppet.conf/agent/report", "true"]
debug: Augeas[puppet_conf](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection
notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet_agent/Augeas[puppet_conf]/returns: executed successfully
```

The date/time of the file has not changed, so it apparently doesn´t change the file. Though, puppet-dashboard shows the file as "changed".
If I put in an "onlyif", that part won´t show up, but I don´t want to repeat everything in the onlyif, also I could only set one config option at a time.

Debian Squeeze
Puppet 2.6.2
Augeas 0.10.0

What is the proper way to configure this?

Comment: Which versions of Puppet, Augeas and ruby-augeas are you using? As a note, `"/files/${puppet_conf}/"` is wrong that is will use `/files//etc/puppet/puppet.conf` which will do a deep-level search. You could also use Camptocamp's [`puppet::config`](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-puppet/blob/master/manifests/config.pp) definition which does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry, I really should no better. Just realized myself that I forgot vital information =/

Comment: @Raphink

Debian Squeeze
Puppet 2.6.2
Augeas 0.10.0
No package "ruby-augeas"

Regarding "context": In the meantime I switched to specifying a lens so speedup things, so context has been removed.

Boy, why is it so hard to edit comments? Enter saves the comment instead of inserting a line break and copied line breaks get removed...

Comment: Just to add, if you're using Puppet 3, you will now get the speedup when specifying only the context without needing to do lens/incl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the version info.  It looks like you're hitting Puppet bug [#11414](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/11414), which is due to a combination of the new Augeas 0.10.0 and an old version of Puppet.

The provider in Puppet is misinterpreting the Augeas version number as being a very old version (string instead of proper version comparison) and it doesn't work as expected.

You'll need to either use Puppet 2.7.18 from [squeeze-backports](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/puppet) (or the [Puppet Labs repo](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/)) which has the bug fix, or use an older or newer version of Augeas (1.0.0 or 0.9.0).

Comment: Thx a lot!  

I grabbed your patch for puppet 2.6 and now I get the expected "Skipping because no files were changed"

    wget https://github.com/domcleal/puppet/commit/e3fc5c49.patch
    patch -u /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/provider/augeas/augeas.rb < e3fc5c49.patch